# Assigning value to the calendar filed

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am working with joomla 3.0.I am just facing the problem with simple application.I have one view.So i've designed a xml file under models folder.Retrieved in view.php.There should be one calandar field.I need to assign current date to that field.How can i do this via php ??
form.xml:

```
<field name="expired" type="calendar" label="Date"
description="Date" format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
required="true" class="readonly" />
```

view.html:

```
$form = $this->get('Form');
$this->form = $form;
```

default.php:

```
<div class="control-group">
<div class="control-label"><?php echo ''Current Date; ?></div>
<div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('created'); ?></div>
</div>
```

How can i apply the current date for this field ??

Comment: Btw, in your default.php, you're calling the field "created", while in  your xml, your field name isn't "created" but "expired", so you should call `$this->form->getInput('expired');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$this->form->setValue('created', '', date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` in your view.html.php file. Doc is here: http://docs.joomla.org/JForm::setValue/11.1

To get the current date, you could also use `JHtml::Date` (http://docs.joomla.org/JHtml::date/11.1) instead of `date()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your model (which should extend JModelForm), you need to override the method loadFormData(), something like (adapt where needed):

```
    // Method to get the data that should be injected in the form.
protected function loadFormData() 
{
    // Check the session for previously entered form data.
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_YOURCOMPONENT.edit.YOURVIEW.data', array());
    if (empty($data)) 
    {
        $data = $this->getItem();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: yes.I already did this.My problem is to show the current date in date field while loading the form.

Comment: The idea is that you could set the $data->created to the current date in this function. That would be another place where you can set a value for the field.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your field in your xml to the following:

```
<field name="expired" 
    type="calendar" 
    label="Date"
    description="Date" 
    format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    required="true"
    filter="user_utc"
    default="now" 
    class="readonly" />
```

Adding the default "now" will load the current date. THe additional filter will set the date to the user time.

Comment: I'd say this is the recommended way if you only want the current date set as the value in case no value is saved already.

Comment: If any value is saved, the default will be overridden with the previously saved value. Note that the class "readonly" doesn't make the field readonly. For this it should be set as `readonly="true"`.